# Example of a cocommutative, non-unimodular Hopf algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, examples-counterexamples, hopf-algebras

**1. Definitions: Unimodularity and cocommutativity**
Let $H$ be a Hopf algebra over a field $\mathbb k$.

- We call $H$ *unimodular* if the space of left integrals $I_l(H)$ is equal to the space of right integrals $I_r(H)$.
- We call $H$ *cocommutative* if $\tau_{H,H} \circ \Delta = \Delta$. Here, $\Delta$ denotes the coproduct of $H$, while $\tau: H \otimes H \rightarrow H \otimes H; v \otimes w \mapsto w \otimes v$ is the twist map.

**2. Question**

- In my lecture notes it says that there are cocommutative, non-unimodular Hopf algebras. What would be an example?
- Apparently, an example is given in *Hopf algebras and their action on rings* by Susan Montgomery. However, due to the pandemic I am unable to get it from the library. If you have a copy and could write down the relevant section, that would be very much appreciated.

**3. My ideas so far**

- The Taft-Hopf algebra $H$ over a field $\mathbb k$ is not an example:
  If $H$ is commutative (i.e. root of unity $\zeta =1_{\mathbb k}$), then $H$ is unimodular. In this case, it is even isomorphic to the boring group algebra of the zero group. Otherwise, $H$ is not cocommutative (even though it is non-unimodular then). Non-cocommutativity follows easily from the observation that the square of the antipode is not the identity (if $\zeta \neq 1_{\mathbb k} $).
- Group algebras:
  As the coproduct of a group algebra is given by the diagonal map any group algebra is cocommutative. However, any group algebra $\mathbb k[G]$ over a *finite* group $G$ is unimodular, since
  $$I_l=I_r=\mathbb k \cdot \sum\limits_{g\in G} g$$ What about infinite groups?
- Regarding the universal enveloping algebra, tensor algebra, symmetric algebra, alternating algebra I am not sure. What can be said here?
- Maybe the following proposition turns out to be useful: A finite dimensional Hopf algebra $H$ is unimodular iff its distinguished group-like element/modular element $a \in G(H^*)$ is equal to the counit $\epsilon_H$. Here, the modular element $a$ is the unique linear form such that $t\cdot h = t a(h)$ for all $h\in H, t\in I_l(H)$. It exists because $t\cdot h \in I_l(H)$ and $I_l(H)$ is one dimensional. It can be shown to be a morphism of algebras, hence a group-like element in $H^*$.

Comment: Just curious, what's Hopf algebra, intuitively?

Comment: @CharlieChang Qiaochu Yuan's post (https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-significance-of-Hopf-algebras) might be helpful. If you have more questions, please open your own thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Google Books' preview](https://books.google.com/books?id=1ePNAwAAQBAJ) of Montgomery's book, page 18:

[image: Montgomery, page 18]

Comment: Thanks. This example (its choice of field) makes sense heuristically, i.e. any example is either infinite-dimensional or a Hopf algebra over a field of characteristic $\neq 0$ (or both). This follows from two propositions: *1. Any finite-dimensional semisimple Hopf algebra is unimodular.* and *2. A cocommutative finite-dimensional Hopf algebra over a field of characteristic zero is semisimple.* The first proposition can be proven using both Maschke's theorem (for Hopf algebras) and the theorem about the distinguished group-like stated in the question. The second proposition follows …

Comment: … from two statements: *2.1. If a Hopf algebra $H$ is cocommutative, then $S^2=id_H$ for the antipode S.* and *2.2. If $S^2=id_H$ and $char(\mathbb k)$ does not divide the dimension of a finite-dimensional $\mathbb k$-Hopf algebra $H$, then $H$ is semisimple.* 2.1. is a tedious calculation (probably best done with string diagrams), while one proof of 2.2. uses the coordinate-free definition of the trace and again Maschke’s theorem.

Comment: Or one could obtain a less general result by the Cartier-Konstant-Milnor-Moore theorem: Any cocommutative, non-unimodular Hopf algebra is either infinite dimensional or its base field is non-algebraically closed or its base field has characteristic $\neq 0$.